Swiper.js changes slides incorrectly. How does the slideNext and slidePrev methods work?
I have custom carousel with 3 elements, active element of it is bigger than other elements.
When I click to the next/prev slide, its seems like ±translate-x-[calc(size-of-active-element+some-space)].
Here is the video. I fixed the screen shaking issue.
Here is my code
{/* Other stuff */}
<div className="w-full relative">
                <Swiper
                    slidesPerView={1}
                    spaceBetween={10}
                    loop={true}
                    slideToClickedSlide={true}
                    navigation={{
                        nextEl: '.no-bro',
                        prevEl: '.yes-bro',
                    }}
                    modules={[Navigation]}
                    breakpoints={{
                        1280: {
                            slidesPerView: 3,
                            spaceBetween: 20,
                        },
                        728: {
                            slidesPerView: 2,
                            spaceBetween: 20,
                        },
                    }}
                >
                    {test.map(image => (
                        <SwiperSlide key={image.id} className="bg-secondary">
                            {({ isActive }) => (
                                <div
                                    className={cn(
                                        'transition-all ease-in-out',
                                        isActive ? 'w-[450px] h-[460px]' : 'w-[310px] h-[380px]'
                                    )}
                                >
                                    {image.id}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    ))}
                </Swiper>
                {/* Other stuff */}
            </div>
{/* Other stuff */}

.swiper-slide {
    width: max-content !important;
}

I had to change '.swiper-slide' constraints so its child element could have right size.
I tried to fix it without changing '.swiper-slide' by setting size and absolute position to '.swiper-active-slide > child-element', but its grand-parent '.swiper' has 'overflow-hidden', and setting it to visible shows other elements of list view that dont need to be seen.
Setting 'loop={false}' does not help.
Help please. I use Next.js/Tailwind/Swiper.js btw.

UPD: Fixed it by setting slidesPerView: 'auto' but got ugly transition. its ok`
